# Is this possible to do in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

You have 2 columns `Link`, `Status` in the db `MyDatabase`.
`Link` column contains strings, the values look like `http://anysite.com/some/more/symbols?...` (`varchar(256)`).
`Status` values could be `NULL` (by default) or `0` or `1` or `2`. (`int(2)`).

How to update column `Status` so that `NULL` will be replaced by `0` or `1` or `2` using this rules:

0) we split Link column by groups depending on its value (links that follow to the same web-site, even to the different pages, are in the same group)

1) for all links in the same group we replace `NULL` with `0`, if Status `0` is at least for 1 link within that group;
for all links in the same group we replace `NULL` with `1`, if Status `1` is at least for 1 link within that group and there are no zeroes;
for all links in the same group we replace `NULL` with `2`, if Status `2` is at least for 1 link within that group and there are no `0` or `1`;
So that `0` has a highest priority, then goes `1`, then `2`, and `NULL` has the lowest priority.

2) if all Status are `NULL` for 1 group, we do nothing.

As a result, the database `MyDatabase`

```
Link                                    Status
--------------------------------------  ------
http://stackoverflow.com/question       NULL
http://google.com/?query=AmIPregnant    2
http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask   NULL
http://google.com/?query=weather        NULL
http://google.com/?query=love           1
http://stackoverflow.com/question/abcd  NULL
```

should become:

```
Link                                    Status
--------------------------------------  ------
http://stackoverflow.com/question       NULL
http://google.com/?query=AmIPregnant    1
http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask   NULL
http://google.com/?query=weather        1
http://google.com/?query=love           1
http://stackoverflow.com/question/abcd  NULL
```

All links contain `http://`, no `https://`, no `ftp://` are in `.com` and have at least `/` symbols after `.com` (this is to simplify the question about this query).

Is it possible to make using just 1 query?

To better understand the question, just guess 1= "I have checked, this web-site contains AT LEAST 1 page in English", 2= "I have checked, this web-site contains AT LEAST 1 page in French", NULL(by default) actually means "I visit 0 pages at this web-site".

The goal is to update the database using just 1 query.

I would guess `SELECT Link as currentlink, Status AS currentstatus FROM MyDatabase WHERE Status is NOT NULL` could be used to select those values that are not null to update the rest of values, but then I'm stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: By same website, do you mean the same domain? Same subdomain? So would google.com be the same as www.google.com or mail.google.com? Or would all 3 be considered distinct groups, even though google.com and www.google.com can both be used for searches?

Comment: Thank you for this question. Yes, http://www.google.com/ and http://mail.google.com/ belong to the same group. But, this question I beleive is much more complicated. I would be happy to get a single query guessing http://mail.google.com and http://www.google.com are different (which is easier for you). That would be fine for me as well. Thank you very much for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use an UDF (store procedure) to do that programatically?

Well, you can try to do it with some UPDATE with sub strings and IF/HAVING structures, but that will be more time expensive. The real way to do that is with a temporal table, or a custom cursor to fetch the rows. Maybe, as the last option, you can find a work around script to do that in a schedule time or with a trigger (when something is affected by... event).

Anyway, please me say it to you, the way that you re looking for is more complex and time expensive that the right way to do it.

Comment: The reason is: server time - first. And the second reason is that I want to update the database with this query only after I review some information and fix the status values. It could be 1 time per several weeks. But, the statuses could be changed manually much more often. It shouldn't be perfect, it should be just good and could contain some mistakes. As result, server doesn't waste time to update the whole db every time I replace some values.